# Failed to install Realm on my ReactNative app ; with: npm ERR! Failed at the realm@3.6.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, realm

I am trying to install Realm for my React Native app with npm. However, I couldn't make it success.

My environment/setup is:

- Windows 10
- Node.js v12.13.0
- npm v6.13.0

I have been trying with this command:
`npm install --save realm`

or specifying the version number:
`npm install --save realm@3.6.0`

but no luck at all. The following error message always prompt without clear hints to me:

```
> realm@3.6.0 install C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/3.6.0/realm-v3.6.0-node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for realm@3.6.0 and node@12.13.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\<UserName>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Projects\\<ProjectFolder>\\node_modules\\realm\\compiled\\node-v72_win32_x64\\realm.node" "--module_name=realm" "--module_path=C:\\Projects\\<ProjectFolder>\\node_modules\\realm\\compiled\\node-v72_win32_x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v72_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v72_win32_x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Projects\\<ProjectFolder>\\node_modules\\realm\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v72_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v72_win32_x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of graphql@0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-sound@^0.10.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-voice@^0.2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@0.19.1 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native-windows@^0.57.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! realm@3.6.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the realm@3.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-21T10_36_02_380Z-debug.log
```

I have followed suggestion from a post of installing older version:
(i.e. [Error installing Realm via npm: npm ERR! Failed at the realm@1.2.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882247/error-installing-realm-via-npm-npm-err-failed-at-the-realm1-2-0-install-scrip))
, and the old successfully version series was 0.x.0 (e.g. 0.14.0), not even 1.x.x, which is far aged version when compared with latest stable version **Realm JavaScript v3.6.0**.

The discussions here with similar error messages are wondering this is a bug:
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/674
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1924

And then I come to this post, which suggest to fallback the whole NodeJS to version 8.x.x for giving it a try:
[Can not install Realm for my React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086365/can-not-install-realm-for-my-react-native-app/51116192)

Is it the only way for installing Realm to my React Native application? As I'm developing on a Windows 10 environment with NodeJS v12.13.0 installed, which I found that fallback procedure / switching between version of different NodeJS are complidated or only feasible on Mac OS/Linux OS. And I'm afraid there may have other side effect of fallback the global NodeJS version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have further read through the details of Realm on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm

There is a statement indicating the necessary of NodeJS of v8 or v10:

> **Getting Started**
>
> Please see the detailed instructions in our docs to use Realm Javascript. Please notice that currently only node.js version 8 and 10 are supported.

So, instead of modifying the global NPM version, I've decided to try with installing a package-wise Node v10.x.x (i.e. in the project folder run `npm install` but not `npm install -g`). And then try to install Realm again. It works like a magic!

So, let me share the steps here for anyone annoying with the same situation:

1. cd to project folder
2. run `npm install node@10.x.x`  (e.g. `npm install node@10.17.0` )
3. run `npm install --save realm` (or specifying the version by: `npm install --save realm@3.6.0` )

---

Running result of installing "local" NodeJS v10:

```
C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>>npm install node@10.17.0

> node@10.17.0 preinstall C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

+ node-win-x64@10.17.0
added 1 package in 1.715s
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of graphql@0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-sound@^0.10.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-voice@^0.2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@0.19.1 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native-windows@^0.57.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ node@10.17.0
added 2 packages from 1 contributor and audited 953911 packages in 19.807s

2 packages are looking for funding.
Run "npm fund" to find out more.
```

Result of installing Realm 3.6.0

```
C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>>npm install --save realm@3.6.0

> realm@3.6.0 install C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[realm] Success: "C:\Projects\<ProjectFolder>\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v64_win32_x64\realm.node" is installed via remote
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of graphql@0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-sound@^0.10.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@2.2.3 requires a peer of react-native-voice@^0.2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@0.19.1 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.2 requires a peer of react-native-windows@^0.57.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ realm@3.6.0
added 62 packages from 32 contributors, removed 1 package and audited 954332 packages in 52.277s

2 packages are looking for funding.
Run "npm fund" to find out more.
```

Comment: Really amazing, it's the simplest solution you can find for such a tedious issue.  Thank you, it really worked very well :)

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Node js is neccessary for realm in react native. I mean iam using react bode and mongodb so it is same. Or i can use only realm with RN

Answer (score 0):

you have to downgrade your nodejs version whether you downgrade globally or locally because for the time Realm supports node v8 to 10 not above than that so try to install node version lesser , ex. npm i node@8 or 10 and than npm i realm --save it'll work